# Entity Framework + stored procedure with paging

Tags: entity-framework, .net-3.5, paging

I am using Entity Framework now and using a stored procedure to populate my entity.
Where there is no problem with populating my entity, but when i trying to bind the result to a gridview control with "Enable Paging" set to true, it gives an error saying 
**"The data source does not support server-side data paging."**

I am using stored procedure because one of the table column is FullTextIndexed, and there is a requirement to be able to search on that field.

Can anyone tell me how the paging would work in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experiences using the DataSource controls.  I usually handle my own data retrieval / binding.  Having said that I would allow the stored procedure to return only the records that are being requested (ie. 10-12 for page 2).